# Getting overlib text value with jquery

Tags: jquery

I got a lot of answers from this website, but now I have a question I couldn't find an anser.

I use overlib to create a popup box when the mousepointer goes over the link. This is what it looks like in HTML code:

```
<div notitieid="notitie1">
<a onMouseOver="return overlib('Here is the popup text', FGCOLOR, '#D7FFD7', BGCOLOR, '#003300', TEXTCOLOR, '#003300', DONOTHING, VAUTO, HAUTO, WIDTH, 400); this.style.cursor='pointer';" onMouseOut="return nd();"><img src="../__pics_small/notitie_vol.png" alt="notitie" border="0" /></a>
</div>
```

I like to get the overlib popup text in a variable in jquery, "Here is the popup text".

Can not figure out how to do this.

Please some help.

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery I'd **highly** suggest you to replace the old overlib with qTip2. By the way, there's no attribute called `notitieid`. If you use it to set data for a script, rename it to `data-notitieid` and access it through jQuery's `.data('notitieid')` function.

Answer (score 0):

The element used by Overlib has the id `overDiv`. Use firebug to examine its structure or test if `$('#overDiv').text()` gives you sufficient results.